# can I configure hibernate properties to connect without using an instance name to sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, hibernate

Can I configure hibernate properties to connect without using an instance name to sql server 2005?  I need to force it to use localhost as the hostname and not specify the instance (same as you can do with the sql server enterprise manager).

Ta!

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You set it up as you normally would in the connection string:

> Server=(local);initial catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI